# Show the following are not connected in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: analysis

> Is the interior, boundary and closure of a connected set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ connected?

I know the interior is not connected we can show it by a counterexample but I am not quite sure for the closure and boundary

Comment: Have you tried to find a proof or counterexample of the closure or boundary?

Answer (score 5):

Not for the interior. Consider two externally tangent closed balls.

Not for the boundary. Consider the end points of a closed segment in $\mathbb R$

Yes for the closure. That is a theorem that you can prove considering continuous constant maps.